# Printing Json data that is in array using rest template in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, resttemplate, pojo

```
@Component
public class JsonData {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    private Date cratedAt;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("imageUrl")
    private String url;

    public JsonData() {

    }

    public JsonData(Integer id, Date cratedAt, String name, String email, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cratedAt = cratedAt;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCratedAt() {
        return cratedAt;
    }

    public void setCratedAt(Date cratedAt) {
        this.cratedAt = cratedAt;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
@RestController
public class JsonDataController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/template/products")
    public void getAllData() {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://5ef99e4bbc5f8f0016c66d42.mockapi.io/testing/data";
        ResponseEntity < JsonData[] > response = template.exchange(url, JsonData[].class);
        for (JsonData jsonData: response.getBody()) {
            System.out.println(jsonData.getName());
            System.out.println(jsonData.getEmail());
        }
    }
}
```

> I am trying to print json data that is array using rest template but I am getting error in this line "ResponseEntity < JsonData[] > response = template.exchange(url, JsonData[].class);" my error is "cannot resolve method" Can anyone tell me correct way of doing this .I am new to spring I do not have proper understanding it would be helpful if some one can give their suggeestion in this code

Comment: You don't need `@Component` on `JsonData` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) does not have any method with signature `exchange(String, Class<T>)`.

That is why you are getting "cannot resolve method" error for `template.exchange(url, JsonData[].class);`.

Here is an example of correct usage of [one of the methods from `RestTemplate.exchange` API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<JsonData[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, JsonData[].class);
```

Comment: I am following this video and in this video he has used exchange method  https://youtu.be/F6lvPHL9Vhg

Comment: @user5474425 yes, but he has also provided a `HttpMethod` and an `HttpEntity` as well. as method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate also has another method - `getForEntity` that makes a GET call with the given URL and expected return type. (without need for passing null for not required fields)

```
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://5ef99e4bbc5f8f0016c66d42.mockapi.io/testing/data";
        ResponseEntity <JsonData[]> response = template.getForEntity(url, JsonData[].class);
```